# Radio module (GNU RADIO) and USB by bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm working actually on an android application. The goal of this app, is to **connect in bluetooth one device (smartphone)** too another device (**raspberry pi**). My radio module is connect **into USB at raspberry p**i.

My application actually can connect in bluetooth with this raspberry pi.
First of all, I want to know if it's possible to get the name of radio module with this app (**port 9100 with bluetooth?**).

Second, I made **flowgraph with GNURADIO**. It works well if want to send informations (FM transmitter). Now I want to **transform this flowgraph in java code** for send information (files, music..) from smartphone to this radio module.

I found this tutorial : http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/GRAndWalkthrough

I just drawed this if you do not understand me (Sorry about my english).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tv93.png)

Is it a good tutorial for my project ?

**Thanks for any help.**

Comment: What kind of connectivity does that Bluetooth link offer? A network socket? A virtual serial port? A simulated audio device?

Comment: Hi ! i do not understand the question ? When i am connected on bluetooth with my smarpthone and raspberry pi,  i can send from my smartphone any files like : photo/video/music...

Comment: Then I don't understand your question, sorry. You have bluetooth hardware. That is used to do bluetooth. What does GNU Radio have to do with it?

Comment: I want to send data from my smartphone to the radio module. First i connect my smartphone with bluetooth into the raspberry pi. Second, i send files from my phone to my raspberry pi. Then I use GNU Radio (installed on raspberry pi) to take the file and send to my radio module. Actually it working but now i want to developt application for automated all tasks.

Comment: ahhh! ok, so this is not about GNU Radio exactly, but about how to stream data via bluetooth from an Android device and then process them in GNU Radio. :) Well, if you just use the bluetooth file transfer profile, streaming is impossible, because that's not what it's designed to do. What kind of data is it that you want to get from Android to Pi?

Comment: ha ha sorry i have a lot of problem to explain my project in english but i am happy you understood what i want to do :). To start I want to transfer any data like song/photo.

Comment: ok, if you could restrict yourself to audio, then this would be easier – simply make your raspberry pi act as a bluetooth speaker for the android phone, and play the song on your phone. Then, use GNU Radio to process the audio from your Pi's audio subsytem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213443/gnu-radio-use-sound-output-as-input-source/32231041#32231041

Comment: oh ok thanks for your answer ! so if i decide to send music file (.wav) from my smartphone. At the moment when the raspberry pi receive the file, my flowgraph in GNU Radio will automatly run or i need to run myself ?

Comment: No, you don't send an Audio *file*, you stream audio! That's the difference here